# Splitting & Moving cell in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a slight problem with my pandas DataFrame.

As the image shows, the first row has `released_date` as "Released 2006" while all other values for the same column have the format "Released MMM DD".

I would like to split the first cell under `released_date` to "Released" and "2006", copy "2006" to year column and subsequently move everything by one column. Any ideas?

Current Format:

```
...|**released_date**| **year** | **genre**  | ...
...| Released   2006 | Arcade   |    Comic   |...
```

Desired output format:

```
...|**released_date**| **year** | **genre**  | ...
...|    Released     |     2006 |     Arcade |...
```

Thanks in advance!!

[image]

Here's the code to read the file in:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("IndieGameCSV/page_1.csv", \
    names=["Windows","Mac","Linux","engine","release_date","year","genre1",\
           "theme","players","score_final","rating", "link" ], index_col=False)
```

and here is the data as seen in the image:

```
True, False, True,Custom Built,Released 2006,Arcade,Comic,Single Player,                     10,1 v, http://indiedb.com/games/tux-climber,
True, True, True,Custom Built,Released Oct 20, 2014,Role Playing,Fantasy,MMO,                     7.3,45 , http://indiedb.com/games/pokemon-planet,
True, True, True,Ren'py,Released May 16, 2015,Turn Based Strategy,Noire,Single Player,                     9,1 v, http://indiedb.com/games/black-closet,
True, True, False,ShiVa3D,Released Jan 2, 2015,First Person Shooter,Sci-Fi,Single Player,                     7.8,4 v, http://indiedb.com/games/kumoon,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.extract.html) method to extract the year:

```
In [11]: df["release_date"].str.extract("(\d{4})")
Out[11]:
0    2006
1    2014
2    2015
3    2015
Name: "release_date", dtype: object
```

---

If you wanted to split the DataFrame you can also look [`.str.match`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.match.html), to check whether a column matches a regex:

```
In [12]: df["release_date"].str.match("Released \d{4}")
Out[12]:
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
Name: "release_date", dtype: bool
```

and index the df with this and ~this.